# Un-Threaded is faster than threaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I have an application that needs to read very big `.CSV` files on application start and convert each row to an `object`. these are the methods that read the files:

```
public List<Aobject> GetAobject()
    {
        List<Aobject> Aobjects = new List<Aobject>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathA, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255")))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] spl = line.Split(',');
                Aobject p = new Aobject { Aprop = spl[0].Trim(), Bprop = spl[1].Trim(), Cprop = spl[2].Trim() };
                Aobjects.Add(p);
            }
        }

        return Aobjects;
    }

    public List<Bobject> GetBobject()
    {
        List<Bobject> Bobjects = new List<Bobject>();

        using (StreamReader sr =
           new StreamReader(pathB, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255")))
        {
            //parts.Clear();
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] spl = line.Split(',');
                Bobject p = new Bobject();
                p.Cat = spl[0];
                p.Name = spl[1];
                p.Serial1 = spl[3].ToUpper().Contains("1");
                if (spl[4].StartsWith("1"))
                    p.Technical = 1;
                else if (spl[4].StartsWith("2"))
                    p.Technical = 2;
                else
                    p.Technical = 0;
                Bobjects.Add(p);
            }
        }

        return Bobjects;
    }
```

this was blocking my `UI` for a few seconds so I tried to make it `multi-Threaded`. however all my tests show that the `un-threaded` scenario is faster. this is how I tested it:

```
 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Dal dal = new Dal();
                Thread a = new Thread(() => { ThreadedAobjects = dal.GetAobject(); });
                Thread b = new Thread(() => { ThreadedBobjects = dal.GetBobject(); });

                a.Start();
                b.Start();

                b.Join();
                a.Join();
            }
            sw.Stop();

            txtThreaded.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();

            Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw2.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Dal dal2 = new Dal();
                NonThreadedAobjects = dal2.GetAobject();
                NonThreadedBobjects = dal2.GetBobject();
            }
            sw2.Stop();

            txtUnThreaded.Text = sw2.Elapsed.ToString();
```

The results:
**Threaded run: `00:01:55.1378686`**
**UnTreaded run: `00:01:37.1197840`**
Compiled for `.Net4.0` but should also work under `.Net3.5`, in release mode.
Could some please explain why does it happen and how can I improve this?

Comment: Creating a thread costs time. You always create a new thread instead of reusing existing threads (thread pool).

Comment: The usual threading answers applies; creating threads are expensive. You could try using the ThreadPool instead. You're also doing parallell IO-work, check your hdd request queue length to see if they are queued up or cached. You could always (crazy idea ahead!) measure what's slow using a cpu profiler.

Comment: Also, what's your hardware? Are both files on same or different drives? Do you have one or several cpu cores? Is the goal to make it load faster, or to ensure that the ui won't lock up?

Comment: What were you measuring for each run? Wall clock time? CPU time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ignoring the cost associated with creating and starting up a thread.  Instead of creating new threads try using the thread pool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => { ThreadedAobjects = dal.GetAobject(); });
```

You'll also need to keep a count of how many operations you have completed in order to properly calculate your total time.  Have a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx

Comment: Thanks, could you please suggest an efficient way to wait for the `ThreadPool` to finish?

Comment: @Yoav the manual reset event pattern shown in the link is pretty efficient albeit not very decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a single thread that calls `GetAobject` and then calls `GetBobject`. Your task is almost certainly I/O bound, and if those two files are very large and on the same drive, then trying to access them concurrently will cause a lot of unnecessary disk seeks. So your code becomes:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
{
    AObjects = GetAObject();
    BObjects = GetBObject();
});
```

That also simplifies your code because you only have to synchronize on one `ManualResetEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will run this test you will get slightly diffrent result every time. the time that takes to things to happend infuanced by many things that happens on the computer while running - in example: other processes, GC, etc.

but your resoults are reasonable because having another thread means that the proccessor need more context-switching and every context swich takes time...

you can read more on context-switch on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Slugart's correct answer: your parallelisation is ineffective in a number of ways, because you wait for first thread to complete, while second one may be completed quicker and doing nothing for some time (Look into Task Parallel Library and PLINQ).

Also, your operations are IO bound, which means parallelism depends on IO device (some devices better perform in sequential manner, and trying to do multiple reads will slow down overall operation).